# Default group permission for RStudio Server

Tags: linux, r, ubuntu, file-permissions, rstudio-server

I am using RStudio server (Version 0.98.994) on Ubuntu 12.04.

Our group works on a external share drive together and would like to open the same project.

When I open a project file created by other colleagues, I got an error with permission denied (Sorry I cannot show the error message as I already changed the permission manually).

After checking the file permission, I found the default permission is "-rw-r--r-x" for *.Rproj and .Rhistory, "drwxr-sr-x" for ".Rproj.user". So no write permission for group.

In the external share drive (no sure about system, should be Linux), the default permission is rw for group.

How could I change the default permission for *.Rproj, .Rhistory and .Rprojt.user?

Thanks for any advice. Please let me know if my question is not clear.

EDIT:

I created new file and folder in the external share drive from command line. The default permission is -rw-rw-r-- for file and drwxrwsr-x for folder, as I expected. It seems RStudio server created these new files with their own default permission.

Could I change the default permission of these files *.Rproj, .Rhistory and .Rprojt.user when RStudio server creates them? i.e. Add write permission to group.

Comment: I think a safer route would be to fork/clone a project (perhaps from GitHub) and work on a project locally. It would also be a good exercise in git/svn and backuping work. Collaboration for writing code isn't like sharing a google doc document, and rightfully so.

Comment: Yes svn/git is the best way to share the codes. But in my base, our supervisor would likes to directly view the students' codes and results.

Answer (score 2):

The default permissions for Directories are `777` which is read/write/execute and for Files it is `666` which is read/write. But then every system has a `umask` value, which is normally `022`.

So when you create a directory it will have permissions 777 but it will take away the `umask` value of 022 and leave you with your default permissions of `755` which is `rwxr-xr-x`

You can change the value of `umask` by simply entering the command

```
umask=055
```

This will set the `umask` value to `055` and whenever you create a new file/directory, `055` will be taken away from the permissions.

Again look at a newly created directory with permissions of `777` and the `umask` value is taken away so the directories permission is `722` which is `rwx-w--w-`
Again look at a new directory with permissions

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I created a new file and folder in the external share drive by myself. The default permission is -rw-rw-r-- for file and drwxrwsr-x for folder. It seems RStudio server created these new files with their own default permission. Will edit my question to clarify this.

Comment: @Bangyou you can put `Sys.umask("002")` at the top of your script or in your .Rprofile

Comment: Thanks for your comments. We have solved our problems through change the default group permission in the share drive.